# How do I move sprites in random directions but with uniform speed python/pygame?

Tags: python, animation, vector, random, pygame

I try to move a set of balls in random movement, but with uniform speed. My code lets the balls move in random directions, but with different speeds. I think it is because the `random.uniform` function gives different values, some close to 0 which, multiplied with the speed and time, gives lower values than the ones closer to 1. But in the animation the speed doesn't seem to be tied with the direction the balls travel (which should be the case if the values of `dx` and `dy` are the cause). I know anout normalization, but I think `random.uniform` gives the same values as a normalized vector?

My questions are:

1. Is the random value of `dx` and `dy` the culprit of the difference in speed?
2. What is the way to make all the balls move in the same speed?

My code:

```
self.timer = pygame.time.Clock()
self.time_passed = self.timer.tick()
self.speed = 0.5
self.dx = random.uniform(-1, 1)
self.dy = random.uniform(-1, 1)
displacement = Vector2(
                       self.dx * (self.speed * self.time_passed),
                       self.dy * (self.speed * self.time_passed)
                       )

self.pos += displacement #both vector objects
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an angle to derive your x and y.

```
self.angle = random.uniform(-1, 1)
self.dy = math.sin(self.angle * math.pi/2)
self.dx = math.cos(self.angle * math.pi/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start with a vector with the desired length (speed) and rotate it by a random angle.

```
self.velocity = Vector2(5, 0).rotate(random.randrange(360))
```

---

Regarding question 1, since you give the vector random x and y values, the resulting vectors will all have completely different lengths/magnitudes, therefore the sprites move with different speeds. For example you could get a `Vector2(0, 0)` and a `Vector2(1, 1)` (it's obvious that they don't have the same length).

You could actually normalize the vectors and then scale them, but better use the rotate method. (Vectors of length zero can't be normalized.)